# Ansible sub tasks in main tasks

Tags: ansible

I want to have 2 "sub tasks" in a main task, but for some reason I am getting a syntax error.

In my `/etc/ansible` directory I have to following structure:

```
playbooks/
         set_users.yml
roles/
     users/
          tasks/
               main.yml
               create_admin.yml
               update_root.yml
          vars/
               main.yml
```

In the `create_admin.yml` file I have the following:

```
---
- name: Create srv_admin user
  user: name=srv_admin password="{{ admin_password }}" groups=wheel shell=/bin/bash
```

And in `update_root.yml`:

```
---
- name Update root password
  user: name=root password="{{ root_password }}"
```

Then I include these tasks in `main.yml`:

```
---
- name: Modify users
  tasks:
    - include: update_root.yml
    - include: create_admin.yml
```

My `vars/main.yml` contains my passwords:

```
---
admin_password: SHA512HASH
root_password: SHA512HAS
```

Now bringing it all together in `playbooks/set_users.yml`:

```
---
- name: create user
  hosts: servers
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - users
```

But I am obviously doing something wrong. When I run the playbook, I get the following error:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/users/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Modify users
  ^ here
```

How can I use these two "sub" tasks in `tasks/main.yml` so that I can simply import the role in the playbook?

EDIT
After implementing @Konstantin Suvorov suggestion:

```
The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/users/tasks/update_root.yml': line 3, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name Update root password
  user: name=root password="{{ root_password }}"
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tasks/main.yml` should be a list of tasks, so no need in `tasks:` keyword:

```
---
- include: update_root.yml
- include: create_admin.yml
```

And avoid using `key=value` syntax, it'll shoot in the leg sometime, use pure YAML:

```
- name: Update root password
  user:
    name: root
    password: "{{ root_password }}"
```

Comment: This helped, but now I get another error. Please see the error above.

Comment: Updated answer. But, please, be kind – read error messages from Ansible.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I am still very new to Ansible and didn't understand the error. I am still trying to grasp the syntax. The updated answer also contains a syntax error, but I could fix it by changing `- name ...` to `- name: ...`

Comment: Yes, copy-paste typo. Fixed.